# Django admin shows all the records in the table in a many to many relationship, instead of related fields

Tags: django, django-admin

So in this project there organizations. Each user can be a manager in multiple organizations. Each user can also be a member of multiple organizations.

When I go to the "user page" in django admin (e.g. I click to users and than click to that user), I expect to see a list of organizations that user is a manager, and another list of organizations that user is a member.

Instead, for any user, I see a list of ALL the organizations in both the managership and membership list, as in the image below. E.g. the list is not filtered by their user id.

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks.

[image: Django admin snip]

My UserAdmin is like:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):

    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        ...
        (_("Managerships"), {"fields": ("managerships", )}),
        (_("Memberships"), {"fields": ("memberships", )}),

    )
    list_display = ["username", "name", "is_superuser"]
    search_fields = ["name"]
```

My user model is like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    managerships = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, related_name='managerships',blank=True)
    memberships  = models.ManyToManyField(Organization,  related_name='memberships',blank=True)
    ...
```

And Organization model is like:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a way Django admin displays m2m fields by default. You see the whole Organization table, and you are able to select which Organizations User belongs to by selecting the rows while holding Control/Command (as written below the box).

However, it may be inconvenient to use multiple-select boxes. There is an option `filter_horizontal` which provides alternative UX (there is also a `filter_vertical`). [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):
    ...
    filter_horizontal = ('managerships', 'memberships')
```

You'll still see the whole Organization table on the left, and the selected Organizations will be shown on the right.